# Angular change ngClass based on key value

Tags: angular

I want to change the color of a button based on the current looping items key
So if the current items looping variable is name then it should be btn-primary, but for all others have btn-warning.

```
            [ngclass]="{'btn-primary': variable.key == 'name'"
             [ngclass]="{'btn-warning': variable.key != 'name'"
```

Comment: Try `[ngClass]="variable.key === 'name' ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-warning'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use logic for add/remove dynamic class using `[ngClass]`

```
[ngClass]="variable.key === 'name' ? 'CLASS1':'CLASS2'"
```

hope it will use for all users !